# Find the day of the week in month

Tags: kotlin, calendar

I want to find the days of the week from the 1st to the end of the month.

The result of writing the code and taking it is different from what I think

May 1st Korean time should be 6 as Saturday, but the result is 3rd Wednesday.

Why is it like this??

This code

```
    val cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Seoul"), Locale.KOREA)
    val DB_year = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR)
    val DB_month = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH)

 
cal.set(DB_year, (DB_month+1), 1)
    when(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)){
            1 -> println("1")
            2 -> println("2")
            3 -> println("3")
            4 -> println("4")
            5 -> println("5")
            6 -> println("6")
            7 -> println("7")

    }
```

Comment: What are the values of `DB_year` and `DB_month`? Note that month is zero-based, so for May you'd need to pass 4, and the value for Wednesday is 4 and not 3 - Sunday is 0.

Comment: The `java.util` time-related classes are all but deprecated. It's less error-prone to use the `java.time` time classes. https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that month starts from 0
Thank you!